Stack navigation for unverified user in react native expo
I'm using react-navigation/stack in my expo app and there's one page the VerifyOTP page that I redirect too once the user signs up on the app for the first time, it will auto-sign him in and then it will redirect to the VerifyOTP page, but the problem is that once it redirects to this page, it doesn't stay open and automatically redirects to the Profile page. Here's my stack with all my screens
import React from 'react';
import {screens} from '../screens';
import TabNavigator from './TabNavigator';
import {Stack, useAppSelector} from '../hooks';

const StackNavigator = () => {
    const isFirstTime = useAppSelector((state) => state.appState.isFirstTime);
    const accessToken = useAppSelector((state) => state.appState.accessToken);
    const refreshToken = useAppSelector((state) => state.appState.refreshToken);
    const user = useAppSelector((state) => state.appState.user);

    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            {isFirstTime && !user && !accessToken && !refreshToken && (
                <Stack.Group>
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name='Onboarding'
                        component={screens.Onboarding}
                        options={{headerShown: false}}
                    />
                </Stack.Group>
            )}
            {!isFirstTime && !user && (
                <Stack.Group>
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name='SignIn'
                        component={screens.SignIn}
                        options={{headerShown: false}}
                    />
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name='SignUp'
                        component={screens.SignUp}
                        options={{headerShown: false}}
                    />
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name='ForgotPassword'
                        component={screens.ForgotPassword}
                        options={{headerShown: false}}
                    />
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name='UnsupportedRegion'
                        component={screens.UnsupportedRegion}
                        options={{headerShown: false}}
                    />
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name='UnsupportedCountry'
                        component={screens.UnsupportedCountry}
                        options={{headerShown: false}}
                    />
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name='TabNavigator'
                        component={TabNavigator}
                        options={{headerShown: false}}
                    />
                </Stack.Group>
            )}
            {!isFirstTime && user && !user.isVerified && (
                <Stack.Group>
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name='VerifyOTP'
                        component={screens.VerifyOTP}
                        options={{headerShown: false}}
                    />
                </Stack.Group>
            )}
            {!isFirstTime && user && (
                <Stack.Group>
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name='TabNavigator'
                        component={TabNavigator}
                        options={{headerShown: false}}
                    />
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name='FAQ'
                        component={screens.FAQ}
                        options={{headerShown: false}}
                    />
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name='OrderHistory'
                        component={screens.OrderHistory}
                        options={{headerShown: false}}
                    />
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name='CustomerSupport'
                        component={screens.CustomerSupport}
                        options={{headerShown: false}}
                    />
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name='Suggestions'
                        component={screens.Suggestions}
                        options={{headerShown: false}}
                    />
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name='Checkout'
                        component={screens.Checkout}
                        options={{headerShown: false}}
                    />
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name='OrderFailed'
                        component={screens.OrderFailed}
                        options={{headerShown: false}}
                    />
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name='OrderSuccessful'
                        component={screens.OrderSuccessful}
                        options={{headerShown: false}}
                    />
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name='TrackYourOrder'
                        component={screens.TrackYourOrder}
                        options={{headerShown: false}}
                    />
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name='EditProfile'
                        component={screens.EditProfile}
                        options={{headerShown: false}}
                    />
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name='AdminOrderDetails'
                        component={screens.AdminOrderDetails}
                        options={{headerShown: false}}
                    />
                </Stack.Group>
            )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
};

export default StackNavigator;

I figured out the problem might be how when the user is first logged in, it sees that the user has signed in and is not yet verified, so then it goes to the VerifyOTP page and then it sees that the user object exists and goes to the TabNavigator page (Profile tab)
       {!isFirstTime && user && (
            <Stack.Group>
                <Stack.Screen
                    name='TabNavigator'
                    component={TabNavigator}
                    options={{headerShown: false}}
                />

Now the problem is I want the user even if he hasn't verified his email to be able to navigate through the app including everything in TabNavigator (Home, Profile, Catalogue)

Damn this site is dead
